# Office JS get reply / forward state and add a Tag in to mail item

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

How do I get the reply/forward state from office JS and according to the state shows tag in email in left pane ?

A tag, similar to the blue and red ones appearing in this image, would appear labeling whether the email has been replied to or not.
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for APIs to check reply/forwad state and tagging?  In your scenario, do you also need to run the code without user action? In the reading pane, even for pinned addins, the addin run when an item is selected.

Comment: Yes I am looking for APIs to check reply/forwad state and tagging ( category ). If it is possible to run the code without user action ?

Answer (score 2):

Answering for Outlook addins, I see this as 3 parts.

1. API to set category is available. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/categories
2. JS API to check reply/forward state is not available for read scenario. You can try graph for this check.
3. It is not possible to run the code without user action.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Since your question is for office js, that's the answer I provided. You can also consider if a background graph service will work for your requirement. (especially tagging without user action) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service.